# Error while installing google colab via pip

Tags: pip

I keep getting this error while trying to install google colab, any ideas?
Here is the following error:

```
pip install google-colab
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting google-colab
  Using cached google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google-colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```